# Adding a new line after enumerate/itemize?

Tags: enumerate, itemize

Right now every time i end an enumerate/itemize i add the following:
`\\`
To obtain a line break. Is there any way to do this only once and not have to keep repeating it??

Comment: Welcome to the site! A new line should begin at the end of a `enumerate`/`itemize` environment by default. Can you show us some complete but minimal code that shows the problem? You can edit this into your question.

Comment: You should almost never need to use `\\ ` in a document other than to end a table row, hard to say what markuo to use without an example document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Everyone's so nice it's rather weird :P

Comment: @Moody WE COULD BE RUDE AND SHOUT AT YOU IF YOU PREFER

Comment: Hahaha. I meant I'm used to low level programming forums where everyone's a bit arrogant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the package `enumitem` and add the following lines to your preamble

```
\setlist[enumerate]{after={\bigskip}}
\setlist[itemize]{after={\bigskip}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{after={\bigskip}}
\setlist[itemize]{after={\bigskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item aaa
  \item bbb
\end{itemize}
Some text

\begin{enumerate}
  \item aaa
  \item bbb
\end{enumerate}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: ah and meanwhile I added an answer I wonder if I should delete mine now or leave it since it's marginally different:-) +1 anyway:-)

Comment: @Moody Glad to help, but to say thanks over here, we accept answers to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). So accept either mine or David's answer (the one that you think helped you most) :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using `\\`in documents.the space around a list is `\topsep` most easily set using the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=1cm}

\begin{document}




aaaa
\begin{enumerate}
\item zzzzz
\item zzzzz
\item zzzzz
\end{enumerate}
aaaaaa


\end{document}
```

Comment: What about if i want to add a new line? Should i still not use \\?

Comment: 9999 times out of 10, when people add `\\ ` to force a line break it would be better if they used some different markup (such as a blank line). but without an example of where you are using this it is hard to say.

Comment: I use it usually like this:
\item Title\\
paragraph
\item Title 2\\
paragraph 2

Comment: You can use backticks  `\`` to show inline code:-) If it is an item title it should be better marked up as such, possibly with `\item[title] paragraph` using a suitable list environment such as `description` or a custom list. As well as making the source file clearer it will give better output, in particular control (suppression) of page break between the title and paragraph

Comment: Anyway, modifying `topsep` you are modifying also the spacing *before* the list and this was not requested by the OP...

Comment: @karlkoeller that's why you got +1 :-)